# How to test load tflite model and test on one image

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have trained the fall and not-fall person detection model using the tflite model maker, and I have tested it while training, but I want to test by loading the tflite file and just giving one image.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python) has the instructions on how to load a TFLite model with python:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test the model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```

Replace the `input_data` with your input image.